# Is it possible to Initialize a static member array dynamically

Tags: c++, static-members

There are so many questions about initializing static members in C++, and yet I couldn't find this one.

```
class Node {

  private:
    static const int INITIAL_SIZE = 100;
    static Node* node_space;
    static int OUT_OF_BOUNDS = 0;
    static Node BAD_NODE;

};

Node* Node::node_space = new Node[Node::INITIAL_SIZE];
```

This seems to work, but I also want to add BAD_NODE to this array as the first element.

```
Node Node::BAD_NODE = Node();
Node::node_space[OUT_OF_BOUNDS] = BAD_NODE;
```

The above doesn't compile. The message is

```
Node.cpp:7: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
```

This is for a school project in which we are implementing a linked list with an array.

Comment: Sorry, but your design is seriously broken! These static fields have *nothing* to do (logically) with a `Node`. Besides, non-`const` `static` members are usually (not always) a sign that something is fishy. You should consider to put your array as member of a `List` object (which then *could* be static, if you really want it). You can then trivially initialise your array in `List::List()`.

Comment: I agree! I was trying to do something weird, a little folly of my own. I have since gone back to a more normal implementation... but the question still stands! Why is what I am doing above not working. Thanks for the architectural advice though, as a student I welcome such comments, as well as discussion of their motivation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may want to-do here, if you only have a single static data-object, but you want to dynamically initialize it, is to create a singleton object as a wrapper around your `Node` class.  Basically what occurs with a singleton is you create a single version of a class that is initialized with a normal class constructor, but the constructor, `operator=()`, and copy-constructor are declared `private`.  Then a single static version of the class is created through a static variable, and there is a public accessor method that allows other portions of your code to access the singleton class (i.e., the accessor returns either a reference or constant reference to the static class you created).

```
class Node_S
{
    private:

        //your original Node class we're wrapping in the singleton object
        struct Node {
            static const int INITIAL_SIZE = 100;
            static Node* node_space;
            static int OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
            static Node BAD_NODE;
        };

        //private default constructor is only called once
        Node_S()
        {
            //place your original initialization code for Node here
            Node::OUT_OF_BOUNDS = 0;
            Node::node_space = new Node[Node::INITIAL_SIZE];
            Node::BAD_NODE = Node();
            Node::node_space[Node::OUT_OF_BOUNDS] = Node::BAD_NODE;
        }

        //private copy and assignment operator
        Node_S(const Node_S&) {}
        Node_S& operator=(const Node_S&) { return *this; }

    public:

        static Node_S& get_instance() 
        {
            //here is where the single version of Node_S is created
            //at runtime
            static Node_S singleton_instance = Node_S();
            return singleton_instance;
        }

        //... Other public functions
};
```

Now you would access your singleton via `Node_S::get_instance()`. Since the copy and assignment operators are declared `private`, you cannot create extra copies of your singleton ... there will only be a single instance of this class created.  If you needed to pass it around, you would do-so by reference.  Furthermore there is no initialization ambiguity because all the static elements of `Node` are initialized in-order during run-time when `get_instance()` is called. Since `singleton_instance` is a static variable, the number of times the constructor `Node_S()` is run is only once, so you can basically place all your initialization code for `Node` safely inside of the constructor.  Then simply add any additional methods required to work with the `Node` type in your `Node_S` interface.  So some common usage code might look like the following:

```
Node_S::Node a_node_copy = Node_S::get_instance().get_node(10);
```

Comment: While it might be correct, this explanation is way too complicated, given the outspoken level of the questioneer.

Comment: Singletons might be a little complicated, but it's a safe, object-oriented method for encapsulating static object initialization and use.  The solution by @Kerrek is excellent as well, but if the automatic graders used in class don't have `-std=c++0x` in their `make` files, then his assignment won't compile ... this is at least compatible with any version of C++.  Plus, I did write the singleton wrapper code for him/her :-)

Comment: Which is also a problem! I appreciate your effort, and I did find this code interesting and educational, but I don't think including it in my project would be smart, considering that it is clearly more complicated than anything I can produce. Thanks though!

Comment: Well, simply create an `init()` function containing the code that you currently have, and call it as one of the first functions in your `main()` so that your static variables are all properly initialized before the rest of your program runs.  That is a pretty simple solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 (i.e "in C++" :-)), you can provide an initialization list for arrays:

```
Node* Node::node_space = new Node[Node::INITIAL_SIZE] { Node::BAD_NODE };
```

This will only work if you mean to set the **first** element to something specific. The initialization list has to provide the initial sequence of elements, so it's not clear what those would be if `OUT_OF_BOUNDS` wasn't zero.

Comment: @Ziggy: Do you have C++11? In GCC, say `-std=c++0x`. *Edit:* Oh, I also forgot the scope for `BAD_NODE`.

Comment: I doubt it. I'm a student, so I have to use what is provided to me. Good answer though!